# what would the following form validation rule mean ? I want a logic that even if one of the form posts are set...it should be allowed

Tags: codeigniter

```
  $this->form_validation->set_rules('newusername', 'newfullname', 'newcity','newemail');
```

// is the set_rules correct. I want that if any one input field with above names are set. It should      pass the validation . Please help me if there are any corrections.

Answer (score 1):

May be you should read the manual again. If you want at least one of them filled, you'll need to write your own validation.

Using the following rules:

```
public $rules = array(
    'newusername' => array(
        'field' => 'newusername',
        'label' => 'New User Name',
        'rules' => 'trim|xss_clean|callback_needone' 
     ),
    'newfullname' => array(
        'field' => 'newusername',
        'label' => 'New Full Name',
        'rules' => 'trim|xss_clean|callback_needone' 
     ),
    'newcity' => array(
        'field' => 'newcity',
        'label' => 'New City',
        'rules' => 'trim|xss_clean|callback_needone' 
     ),
    'newemail' => array(
        'field' => 'newemail',
        'label' => 'New Email',
        'rules' => 'trim|xss_clean|callback_needone' 
     )
 )
```

in your controller you have to write

```
public function needone(){
   if ( empty($this->input->post('newusername')) && empty($this->input->post('newfullname')) && empty($this->input->post('newcity')) && empty($this->input->post('newmail')) ) {
     $this->form_validation->set_message('needone', 'At least one field must be entered');
      return FALSE;
   }
   return TRUE;
}
```

Put the rule on any of the form's fields, or all of them to hilite those who are in the required group, it's up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Each input field in your form, requires it's own validation rules. Which should look like this;

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('field name', 'human name', 'rules');
```

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#validationrules

So, you would have 4 set_rules functions, like this;

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('newusername', 'New username', 'trim|xss_clean|required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('newfullname', 'New full name', 'trim|xss_clean|required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('newcity', 'New City', 'trim|xss_clean|required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('newemail', 'New Email', 'trim|xss_clean|required');
```

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#cascadingrules

Here's a rule reference, all the available rules;

https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#rulereference

---

Now, to check if **ANY** of the items are set, I would do this;

```
if ($this->input->post('newusername') OR $this->input->post('newusername') OR $this->input->post('newusername') OR $this->input->post('newusername'))
{
    // One of them is set
}
else
{
    // Nothing is set
}
```

Comment: You should add a callback to include the condition. See the first answer, it's a callback